# "Do not show again" checkbox to hide a JFrame

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, jcheckbox

I've written a little program that generates a "Welcome Email" for the Helpdesk Team in my office, that is sent out to new starters. I've recently made some changes, and created a changelog JFrame that pops-up when the program is run. I've included a "Don't show again" checkbox, but can't figure out how to stop this JFrame from popping up after the checkbox is ticked.

Here's the code:

Main class calls this to bring up the changelog JFrame:

```
private ChangeLog aFrame;
aFrame = new ChangeLog();
aFrame.setVisible(aFrame.logCheckBox);
```

This is the code from ChangeLog class:

```
protected boolean logCheckBox;
private final ChangeLogButtonEvent changeLogEvent;


public ChangeLog() {
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(this);
    logCheckBox = true;
    changeLogEvent = new ChangeLogButtonEvent();
    jCheckBox1.addItemListener(changeLogEvent);        
}

 private final class ChangeLogButtonEvent implements ItemListener{
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged (ItemEvent e){
        if(jCheckBox1.isSelected())
        {
            logCheckBox = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the problem is with the fact that logCheckBox is being set to true each time the program is run, but I'm not sure how to do it otherwise.

Thanks in advance.

Tom.

Comment: write your condition to a **file** then check it on run so if checked dont show, your program reset as soon as it is relaunced

Comment: You need to re-think your problem. It's more generally one of "how do I persist program state", here the state being the checkbox state. If you're using multiple users in a server environment, then this data would go into the database.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks. I will use JDBC for this then.